# AsyncTast not calling onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-asynctask

Here's a part of a code that should do something and then call the onPostExecute event. 

For some reason, it doesn't call it, and in eclipse I can see that the method is marked with yellow (not used method)...

I cant understand why its this way...

Do you know why?

Thank you!

PS: I looked into some posts here and didn't find my solution...

```
    final ImageButton sync = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.syncChanges);
    sync.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sync.setImageResource(R.drawable.none);
            sync.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
            final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =  (AnimationDrawable) sync.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
             class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
                 protected String[] doInBackground(String...strings) {
                    try {
                        OptionScraper.run(strings[0], Integer.parseInt(strings[1]));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return OptionScraper.GetChanges();
                 }
                    protected void onPostExecute() {
                    InitChangesToText();
                    frameAnimation.stop();
                    sync.setImageResource(R.drawable.sync);
                 }
             }
             new DownloadFilesTask().execute(classLetter,classNum);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not overriding `onPostExecute()` correctly. It takes one argument *(the object you return from `doInBackground()`)*. But you override/create the method with a signature that takes no arguments. Which means that the framework calls the default implementation instead of your own. Which does nothing at all.

So change

```
protected void onPostExecute() {
```

to

```
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
```

in this case. 
I also recommend adding an `@Override` annotation to that method, in this case eclipse or a similar tool should have pointed that out in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

get the AsyncTask out of the new OnClickListener(). Define it directly as private class in your Activity.

Comment: When the class is private it says : Illegal modifier for the local class DonloadFilesTask; only abstract or final is permitted